# What does &>> sign mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala. I am trying to understand the following. But there is this sign `&>>`. I don't know the meaning of this sign. Google search hasn't been helpful either. What does this `&>>` sign mean? Below is the code:

```
val consume8MB = takeLines[Array[Byte]](1024 * 1024 * 8) &>> Iteratee.consume()
```

Comment: It's most likely a library method from some library you are using.  What type results from `takeLines`?  Look at that type and `&>>` might be defined there, or on some pimping that is tied to that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used in Play Framework to transform a stream of data, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Enumeratees